# UI scrambles on model create

Tags: odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

I have a model:

```
class MyModel:
    name = ...
    field1 = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='sale.order')

    @staticmethod
    def _do_some(env, inst):
        ... 

        env['stock.picking'].create(vals={
            'move_type': 'direct',
            'company_id': delivery_order.company_id.id,
            'picking_type_id': pick_type_id
        }) # UI Scrambles when this happens


        ...

    @onchange('field1')
    def field1_changed(self):
        # self.id is a NewId ... which makes no sense

        # this_inst is a replacement for self (because of NewId)
        this_inst = ... I search this instance by name

        MyModel._do_some(self.env, this_inst)
```

I have a view that has a dropdown field for `MyModel.field1` which when I change naturally calls `MyModel.field1_changed`, which in turn calls `MyModel._do_some`.

After `create` is being called on the `stock.picking` model, my UI scrambles, and what I mean by that is that all the field values of the `MyModel` instance are erased from the view and also it seems that validation prevents me from saving because of "missing required fields".

Answer (score 0):

The `onchange` generally does not permit database operations, and that is the reason for `self.id` being an instance of `NewId`.

Overwrite the `write` function and check when the write is for `field1` and do your database operations. Advantage: `self.id` is not `NewId` but is the actual id.